# Python IBAN validation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple Python IBAN validator, which I'd like some reviews on.

#### INTRO

Quoting from wikipedia, we know that:

> The International Bank Account Number (IBAN) is an internationally
>   agreed system of identifying bank accounts across national borders to
>   facilitate the communication and processing of cross border
>   transactions with a reduced risk of transcription errors.

Now, an IBAN may look like this: **GB82WEST12345698765432**

There are three algorithms to validate an IBAN:

1. Validating the IBAN
2. Generating IBAN check digits
3. Modulo operation on IBAN

I used only the first 2 methods in my program.

---

#### 1. Validating the IBAN

Description (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Validating_the_IBAN)):

> An IBAN is validated by converting it into an integer and performing a
>   basic mod-97 operation (as described in ISO 7064) on it. If the IBAN
>   is valid, the remainder equals 1. The algorithm of IBAN
>   validation is as follows:
>
> Check that the total IBAN length is correct as per the country. If
>   not, the IBAN is invalid Move the four initial characters to the end
>   of the string Replace each letter in the string with two digits,
>   thereby expanding the string, where A = 10, B = 11, ..., Z = 35
>   Interpret the string as a decimal integer and compute the remainder of
>   that number on division by 97 If the remainder is 1, the check digit
>   test is passed and the IBAN might be valid.
>
> Example (fictitious United Kingdom bank, sort code 12-34-56, account
>   number 98765432):
>
> ```
> • IBAN:                   GB82WEST12345698765432  
> • Rearrange:              WEST12345698765432GB82  
> • Convert to integer:     3214282912345698765432161182    
> • Compute remainder:      3214282912345698765432161182    mod 97 = 1
> ```

---

#### 2. Generating IBAN check digits

Description (from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number#Generating_IBAN_check_digits)):

> According to the ECBS "generation of the IBAN shall be the exclusive
>   responsibility of the bank/branch servicing the account".[8] The ECBS
>   document replicates part of the ISO/IEC 7064:2003 standard as a method
>   for generating check digits in the range 02 to 98. Check digits in the
>   ranges 00 to 96, 01 to 97, and 03 to 99 will also provide validation
>   of an IBAN, but the standard is silent as to whether or not these
>   ranges may be used.
>
> The preferred algorithm is:
>
> 1. Check that the total IBAN length is correct as per the country.If
>      not, the IBAN is invalid. (I skipped this)
> 2. Replace the two check digits by 00 (e.g. GB00
>      for the UK)
> 3. Move the four initial characters to the end of the string
> 4. Replace the letters in the string with digits, expanding the string as
>      necessary, such that A or a = 10, B or b = 11, and Z or z = 35. Each
>      alphabetic character is therefore replaced by 2 digits
> 5. Convert the string to an integer (i.e. ignore leading zeroes)
> 6. Calculate mod-97 of the new number, which results in the remainder        > 7. Subtract the remainder from 98, and use the result for the two check digits. If the result is a single digit number, pad it with a leading 0 to make a two-digit number

---

#### Code (Python 3)

```
letter_dic = {"A": 10, "B": 11, "C": 12, "D": 13, "E": 14, "F": 15, "G": 16, "H": 17, "I": 18, "J": 19, "K": 20,
              "L": 21, "M": 22, "N": 23, "O": 24, "P": 25, "Q": 26, "R": 27, "S": 28, "T": 29, "U": 30, "V": 31,
              "W": 32, "X": 33, "Y": 34, "Z": 35,
              "0": 0, "1": 1, "2": 2, "3": 3, "4": 4, "5": 5, "6": 6, "7": 7, "8": 8, "9": 9}

letters = {ord(k): str(v) for k, v in letter_dic.items()}


def chech_validation_chars_iban(iban):
    zeros_iban = iban[:2] + '00' + iban[4:]
    iban_inverted = zeros_iban[4:] + zeros_iban[:4]
    iban_numbered = iban_inverted.translate(letters)

    verification_chars = 98 - (int(iban_numbered) % 97)

    if verification_chars < 10:
        verification_chars = '{:02}'.format(int(verification_chars))
    return verification_chars


def validate_iban(iban):
    iban_inverted = iban[4:] + iban[:4]
    iban_numbered = iban_inverted.translate(letters)

    return int(iban_numbered) % 97


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_iban = 'RO13RZBR0000060007134800'

    if chech_validation_chars_iban(my_iban) == int(my_iban[2:4]):
        if validate_iban(my_iban) == 1:
            print('IBAN ok!\n')
        else:
            print('IBAN nok!\n')
    else:
        print('IBAN nok!\n')
```

Any advice on what could go wrong, tips or improvements are welcome!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Changes I'd make, from the top down:

- Use [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html) with `enumerate` to make the dictionary. Rather than manually making one.
- `letters` is a constant, so use `LETTERS`.
- Make a new function to change the layout of an IBAN and change it to a number.
- Rename `chech_validation_chars_iban` to the name `generate_iban_check_digits` as it's not a check, it's a transform.
- Change the format to use strings, `{:0>2}`, and remove the if.
- Change `validate_iban` to check if it's a valid IBAN, and so return a boolean.
- Use `and` to reduce the amount of ifs.

This resulted in:

```
import string
LETTERS = {ord(d): str(i) for i, d in enumerate(string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase)}


def _number_iban(iban):
    return (iban[4:] + iban[:4]).translate(LETTERS)


def generate_iban_check_digits(iban):
    number_iban = _number_iban(iban[:2] + '00' + iban[4:])
    return '{:0>2}'.format(98 - (int(number_iban) % 97))


def valid_iban(iban):
    return int(_number_iban(iban)) % 97 == 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_iban = 'RO13RZBR0000060007134800'
    if generate_iban_check_digits(my_iban) == my_iban[2:4] and valid_iban(my_iban):
        print('IBAN ok!\n')
    else:
        print('IBAN not ok!\n')
```

There is one glairing problem with this, the specification states that it allows both upper and lowercase input:

> Replace the letters in the string with digits, expanding the string as necessary, such that A or a = 10, B or b = 11, and Z or z = 35. Each alphabetic character is therefore replaced by 2 digits

However we only allow uppercase. To amend this I'd change the letters dict to include the lowercase letters.
But makes the code a little harder to read, and not as clean.
And so the cleanest way would probably be to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), with the method we're using now.

```
_LETTERS = chain(enumerate(string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase),
                 enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase, 10))
LETTERS = {ord(d): str(i) for i, d in _LETTERS}
```

Comment: Instead of `return '{:0>2}'.format(98 - (int(iban_numbered) % 97))` you meant `return '{:0>2}'.format(98 - (int(number_iban) % 97))`, right ? Thanks for the answer, it's awesome.

Comment: @Dex'ter Yeah, I don't know why I didn't change both of them... Silly me

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the letter to digit conversion using regex and lambda function:

```
re.sub('[A-Z]', lambda m: str(ord(m.group()) - 55), (iban[4:] + iban[:4]))
```

Translate replaces characters by one digit AFAIK. Therefore might not be the optimal choice for this IBAN use-case.

Comment: What do you mean by "Translate replaces characters by one digit"? `'A'.translate(LETTERS)` -> `'10'` for me.